# Enable Thrift in Cassandra Docker

Tags: cassandra, docker, thrift

I'm trying to start up a docker image that runs cassandra. I need to use thrift to communicate with cassandra, but it looks like that's disabled by default. Checking out the cassandra logs shows:

```
INFO  21:10:35 Not starting RPC server as requested. 
  Use JMX (StorageService->startRPCServer()) or nodetool (enablethrift) to start it
```

My question is: how can I enable thrift when starting this cassandra container?

I've tried to set various environment variables to no avail:

```
docker run --name cs1 -d -e "start_rpc=true" cassandra
docker run --name cs1 -d -e "CASSANDRA_START_RPC=true" cassandra
docker run --name cs1 -d -e "enablethrift=true" cassandra
```

Comment: Apparently, thrift RPC server was disabled since Cassandra 2.2, you need to set start_rpc=true, nodetool enablethrift for newer versions so clients can use thrift.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9319

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've been having the same problem with the Docker Cassandra image. You can use my docker container on [Github](https://github.com/jimthedev/cassandra) or on [Docker hub](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/jimthedev/cassandra/) instead of the default Cassandra image.

The problem is that the cassandra.yaml file has start_rpc set to false. We need to change that. To do that we can use the following Dockerfile (which is what my image does):

```
FROM cassandra
RUN sed -i 's/^start_rpc.*$/start_rpc: true/' /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
```

Comment: THANKS! I had the same issue. But instead of using your fork (which likely will eventually be abandonned :-( ), I am simply running `docker exec -it cass1 sed -i 's/^start_rpc.*$/start_rpc: true/' /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml` after running the official container. That works too!

Answer (score 29):

The `sed` workaround (and subsequent custom Dockerfiles that enable only this behavior) is no longer necessary.

Newer [official Docker containers](https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra/) support a `CASSANDRA_START_RPC` environment variable using the `-e` flag.  For example:

```
docker run --name cassandra1 -d -e CASSANDRA_START_RPC=true -p 9160:9160 -p 9042:9042 -p 7199:7199 -p 7001:7001 -p 7000:7000 cassandra
```

Comment: Thanks Les! Perfect!

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to expose the thrift client API port with the `run` command to be able to access the container from outside like:

```
docker run --name cs1 -d .... -p 9160:9160 cassandra
```

You might also want to expose more ports, like for CQL port 9042, port 7199 for JMX, port 7000 and 7001 for internode communication.