# Cassndra Docker Image stops if I start Node2

Tags: docker, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am installing Cassandra first time. Here I am using commands to run **Node1** and **Node2**

- **Node1**

```
docker run --name cassandra-node-1 -d -e CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME="docker_test"  -e CASSANDRA_NUM_TOKENS="8"  -e CASSANDRA_DC="dc1"  -e CASSANDRA_RACK="rack1"  -e CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_SNITCH="GossipingPropertyFileSnitch" -p 9042:9042  -v /path/to/Cassandra/data/node1:/var/lib/cassandra/data cassandra:latest
```

- **Node2**

```
docker run --name cassandra-node-2 -d -e CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME="docker_test"  -e CASSANDRA_NUM_TOKENS="8"  -e CASSANDRA_DC="dc1"  -e CASSANDRA_RACK="rack2”  -e CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_SNITCH="GossipingPropertyFileSnitch"  -e CASSANDRA_SEEDS="$(docker inspect --format='{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' cassandra-node-1)”  -p 9043:9042  -v /path/to/Cassandra/data/node2:/var/lib/cassandra/data cassandra:latest
```

As soon as Node2 goes up, Node1 containers get stopped. What am I doing wrong?

**Docker Version Related**

```
docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.12.5
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.4
 Git commit:   7392c3b
 Built:        Fri Dec 16 06:14:34 2016
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.5
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.4
 Git commit:   7392c3b
 Built:        Fri Dec 16 06:14:34 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

**Update**

Docker Logs tell this:

```
INFO  [main] 2019-05-14 01:51:07,230 Server.java:156 - Starting listening for CQL clients on /0.0.0.0:9042 (unencrypted)...
INFO  [main] 2019-05-14 01:51:07,336 CassandraDaemon.java:556 - Not starting RPC server as requested. Use JMX (StorageService->startRPCServer()) or nodetool (enablethrift) to start it
```

**Update2**

Changed Run command by adding `-e CASSANDRA_START_RPC=true -p 9042:9042 -p 9160:9160 -p 7199:7199 -p 7001:7001 -p 7000:7000`, find no JMX error but docker container of Node1 STILL exits.

I am using Docker for Mac OS

Comment: Just can tell you both 2 containers alive on my side...

Comment: I am getting RPC error in logs. I am on Mac

Comment: ` Not starting RPC server as requested. 
  Use JMX (StorageService->startRPCServer()) or nodetool (enablethrift) to start it`

Comment: No idea, wait others. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31620494/enable-thrift-in-cassandra-docker? But it's strange on ubuntu it will be ok.

Comment: @atline I am using Docker for Mac

Comment: Are you running these two node on same machine where you built these images.?

Comment: @ChandrakantAudhutwar Yes offcourse. I am on Docker

Answer (score 1):

It was memory issue. Docker memory was 2GB, I increased and it started and not exited.

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer will help you [Enable Thrift in Cassandra Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31620494/enable-thrift-in-cassandra-docker)

You have a problem with RPC. By default seted to false. Need to turn it to true.

`-e CASSANDRA_START_RPC=true`

Comment: If you notice the update, I already did this, it still exited.